# How to transform an equation in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The equation is 
$$
p_i(k+1)=p_i(k)+{T\over l_i}(q_i(k)-q_{i+1}(k)-r_i(k)-f_i(k))
$$
$$
k \in \{1,\dots,N\} \quad i\in \{1,\dots,n\}
$$
where
$$
p_i(k),p_i(k+1),q_i(k),q_{i+1}(k)
$$
are unknown,
$$
r_i(k),f_i(k) 
$$
are know.

Transform the equation above into $Ax=b$.

Comment: What is the question?